# I want to copy a .wav file from my current system to linux server using python

Tags: python, ssh, copy, command, scp

Any one have idea then please suggest, This is how I'm doing now. bt not working.
Here I'm trying to copy my newtext.wav file to server location.

```
def copyToServer():  
     success =  os.system("scp D:/AMRITESH/ContractMonitoring/newtext.wav       
             root@xxx.xxx.x.xxx:/usr/share/asterisk/sounds")

    if (success != True):
         print(success)

         print "Connection Error"
    else:
         print "Connection Established"
```

Comment: “Not working” is not a problem description. Is there an error message or a traceback? If so, add it to your question.

Comment: No error message I'm getting

Comment: so what does “not working” mean in this case?

Comment: No working in the sence it should copy my file to the destination that is not working

Comment: Does this work if you execute the command in a terminal?

Comment: scp as used in your script might ask for passwords - which could be the case it's not working

Comment: No, I'm getting this message:   ssh: Could not resolve hostname D: Name or service not known

Comment: Any  idea about this

Comment: Resolve the issue by below code

Comment: def createSSHClient(server, port, user, password):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(server, port, user, password)
    print "Connection Established Here"
    return client

Answer (score 0):

```
def createSSHClient(server, port, user, password):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(server, port, user, password)
    print "Connection Established Here"
    return client

ssh = createSSHClient('xxx.xxx.x.xxx', 'xx', 'username', 'password')
    scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
    print "Sending file to server"
    scp.put('D:/AMRITESH/ContractMonitoring/'+fileName, '/usr/share/asterisk/sounds')
```